# Why does my highscore saving output "TypeError: unsupported types for __ge__: 'int', 'list'" in micropython?

Tags: save, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, tetris

Why does my highscore saving output "TypeError: unsupported types for **ge**: 'int', 'list'" in micropython?

I tried making my Tetris game on my RaspberryPi Pico be able to save highscores, but I kept getting errors. I dont understand whats wrong with my code. I've tried looking up how to save highscores, none of them worked. :(

```
        def game_over_screen():
            pgb.fill_rect(240-240,240-240,240,240,PicoGameBoy.color(0,0,0))
            pgb.fill_rect((GRID_OFFSET+GRID_COLS+1)*BLOCK_SIZE+1,16*BLOCK_SIZE,
                          BLOCK_SIZE*7,BLOCK_SIZE*2,
                          TEXT_BACKGROUND_COLOR)
            pgb.text("LINES",(GRID_OFFSET+GRID_COLS+2)*BLOCK_SIZE+1,16*BLOCK_SIZE+1,TEXT_COLOR)
            pgb.text("%8s" % lines,(GRID_OFFSET+GRID_COLS+2)*BLOCK_SIZE+1,17*BLOCK_SIZE+1,TEXT_COLOR)
            if score >= highscore:
                highscore.pop(0)
                highscore.append(score)
            pgb.fill_rect((GRID_OFFSET+GRID_COLS+1)*BLOCK_SIZE+1,16*BLOCK_SIZE,
                          BLOCK_SIZE*7,BLOCK_SIZE*2,
                          TEXT_BACKGROUND_COLOR)
            pgb.text("HIGHSCORE",(GRID_OFFSET+GRID_COLS+2)*BLOCK_SIZE+1,16*BLOCK_SIZE+1,TEXT_COLOR)
            pgb.text("%8s" % highscore,(GRID_OFFSET+GRID_COLS+2)*BLOCK_SIZE+1,17*BLOCK_SIZE+1,TEXT_COLOR)
            # draw text (LEVEL)
            pgb.fill_rect((GRID_OFFSET+GRID_COLS+1)*BLOCK_SIZE+1,13*BLOCK_SIZE,
                          BLOCK_SIZE*7,BLOCK_SIZE*2,
                          TEXT_BACKGROUND_COLOR)
            pgb.text("LEVEL",(GRID_OFFSET+GRID_COLS+2)*BLOCK_SIZE+1,13*BLOCK_SIZE+1,TEXT_COLOR)
            pgb.text("%8s" % level,(GRID_OFFSET+GRID_COLS+2)*BLOCK_SIZE+1,14*BLOCK_SIZE+1,TEXT_COLOR)
            
            # draw text (SCORE)
            pgb.fill_rect((GRID_OFFSET+GRID_COLS+1)*BLOCK_SIZE+1,10*BLOCK_SIZE,
                          BLOCK_SIZE*7,BLOCK_SIZE*2,
                          TEXT_BACKGROUND_COLOR)
            pgb.text("SCORE",(GRID_OFFSET+GRID_COLS+2)*BLOCK_SIZE+1,10*BLOCK_SIZE+1,TEXT_COLOR)
            pgb.text("%8s" % score,(GRID_OFFSET+GRID_COLS+2)*BLOCK_SIZE+1,11*BLOCK_SIZE+1,TEXT_COLOR)
            #pgb.fill_rect(60,90,120,240,BLACK)
            pgb.center_text("GAME OVER",WHITE)
            pgb.show()
            while True:
                time.sleep(0.500)
```

When I run it, it outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 608, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 409, in game_over_screen
TypeError: unsupported types for __ge__: 'int', 'list'
```

Answer (score 1):

Score is an integer value and highscore is a list of integer values, so you cant directly compare the two. You need to walk through the list of highscores and compare each one with the score. Or you could just append the new score, sort the highscores and keep the top 3.

```
highscore = []

def update_highscore(new_score):
    highscore.append(new_score)   # append the new score
    highscore.sort(reverse=True)  # Sort the scores in descending order

    # Keep only the top three scores
    if len(highscore) > 3:
        highscore.pop()

update_highscore(100)
print(highscore)

update_highscore(300)
print(highscore)

update_highscore(250)
print(highscore)

update_highscore(150)
print(highscore)
```

Comment: How do I make the highscore save for when it get run again?